# Attaching two components to the same event in java/android how to distinguish between each component

Tags: java, android

Self taught PHP, now learning java and javascript.

In java/android is it good practice to add the same event listener to different components and how does one tell which component is in use?

```
//set up view components
listTitleET     = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.listTitleEditText);
finishDateET    = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.finishDateEditText);

startDateET.setOnFocusChangeListener(v);        
finishDateET.setOnFocusChangeListener(v);

View.OnFocusChangeListener v = new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {           
            /************* 
             * Do something here
             * But how does one know which event is in use ..?

    }
};
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always prefer to have a separate event listener for each component, or to create a class that extends the event listener and have a separate instance for each. I think it is cleaner and eaiser to maintain as it avoids long `switch` or `if...else if` statements. So, You can do a few different things: Create two different instances of `View.OnFocusChangedListener` say `v1` and `v2` and use

```
startDateET.setOnFocusChangeListener(v1);        
finishDateET.setOnFocusChangeListener(v2);
```

Where the overridden methods have the appropriate code corresponding to each view.

Or you can set an id or tag on each of your `EditText` views and then have some logic like

```
if(v.getId.equals(...))
...
else if (v.getId().equals(...))
...
```

inside the overridden method. As you can see, if you choose to edit your code later you may have to untangle a long such if/switch statement.

Comment: thanks so much, just what I was after! The if else suits me fine

Comment: ...Two views should be no problem with an if statement. It is only when there are many views that is starts to get messy

Answer (score 1):

The argument "v" in the `onFocusChange` method tells you which `View` triggers the event.

From there you can even access the listener from the listener itself, through:

```
v.getOnFocusChangeListener();
```

Note that I advise you to change the listener's name to something other than "v", it's quite confusing otherwise.

**Edit**

Note: if you require to access references to any component, etc. outside the anonymous class (your listener), you must declare the component (or anything) `final`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same listener for example with onClick, you use something like this:

```
View.OnClickListener myListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
     switch(v.getId())
     {
       case R.id.button:
       { 
        //do something
         break;
       }

       case R.id.button2 :
       {
         //do something
         break;
       }
     }
}
```

You only need to know which view throw the event.